# How to exit application when C# ServiceBusClient can't connect to Service Bus

Tags: c#, .net-core, azureservicebus, .net-7.0, servicebus

When my .NET 7 worker service application can not connect to a service bus instance, I want it to error/exit. I see an error in the logs:

> [ERR] ErrorHandler invoked with ErrorSource: Receive, FullyQualifiedNamespace: EntityPath, Exception: Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusException: The requested name is valid, but no data o...

However, no exception is throw to my code, and it just keeps retrying this endlessly instead of exiting:

> [WRN] RunOperation encountered an exception and will retry. Exception: Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusException: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found. ErrorCode: NoData (ServiceCommunicationProblem).

I can not find where these logs come from, or intercept the exception, presumably from Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus

**Question**: how can I make my application throw an exception and exit when it can not connect to service bus / when the above happens?

**Implementation details**

In my application I configure a worker, and my `ServiceBusClient` in `program.cs` as follows:

```
services.AddHostedService<ServiceBusWorker>();
services.AddAzureClients(clientsBuilder =>
{
    clientsBuilder.AddServiceBusClient(serviceBusConfiguration?.ConnectionString)
      .WithName(serviceBusConfiguration?.MyQueue);
});
```

Then in my worker I construct as follows::

```
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;

public ServiceBusWorker(IAzureClientFactory<ServiceBusClient> serviceBusClientFactory)
{
    _serviceBusClientFactory = serviceBusClientFactory;

    var connectionString = serviceBusConfiguration.Value.ConnectionString;

    _requestQueueClient = _serviceBusClientFactory.CreateClient(_requestQueue);
```

And the worker starts as follows:

```
public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        await using var requestProcessor = _requestQueueClient.CreateProcessor(_requestQueue, _serviceBusProcessorOptions);

        // configure the message and error handler to use
        requestProcessor.ProcessMessageAsync += ProcessMessageAsync;
        requestProcessor.ProcessErrorAsync += ErrorHandler;

        await requestProcessor.StartProcessingAsync(cancellationToken);

        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) { await Task.Delay(1000, cancellationToken); } //Need to improve. Required to keep the requestProcessor alive for now until better solution.
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, "Error when starting the request processor");
        throw;
    }
}
```

**What I tried**

I have tried to configure a retry policy in program.cs as follows, but it doesn't make a difference, I assume because it relates to message retries and not my scenario:

```
services.AddAzureClients(clientsBuilder =>
{
    var serviceBusRetryOptions = new ServiceBusRetryOptions
    {
        MaxRetries = 3,
        Delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
        TryTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
    };

clientsBuilder
.AddServiceBusClient(serviceBusConfiguration?.ConnectionString)
.ConfigureOptions(options =>
    {
        options.RetryOptions = serviceBusRetryOptions;
    })
.WithName(serviceBusConfiguration?.RequestQueue);

clientsBuilder
.AddServiceBusClient(serviceBusConfiguration?.ConnectionString)
.ConfigureOptions(options =>
    {
        options.RetryOptions = serviceBusRetryOptions;
    })
.WithName(serviceBusConfiguration?.ResponseQueue);
});
```

Comment: Note that instead of using a while loop to poll on `Task.Delay`, you can just call `Task.Delay(-1, cancellationToken)` directly. It will register with the cancellation token to stop delaying when cancellation is requested.

Comment: @jhmckimm Thanks for that note. My main question is, how can I make my application detect that the service bus connection is failing and then do whatever I want when I have detected that? Or, make the azure service bus package / client throw exception / exit for me?

Answer (score 0):

You can inject [`IHostApplicationLifetime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-7.0#ihostapplicationlifetime) into your worker and call `_hostApplicationLifetime.StopApplication()` to stop your application gracefully.

Comment: My question is, how can I make my application detect that the service bus connection is failing and then do whatever I want when I have detected that? Or, make the azure service bus package / client throw exception / exit for me?